# Nunit integration in a window application in VS2005 using C#

Tags: c#, nunit

I'm developing a **window application** in VS2005 using C#. I need to integrate NUnit into my project. Mainly i need to implement the 'Execute' option available in NUint. How can i do this.?

Comment: Please clarify; do you want to use NUnit during development? Or in your deployed application?

Answer (score 1):

[TestDriven.Net](http://testdriven.net/) is a .Net Plugin in Vs2005 which will help you achieve it.

Comment: my application generates a dll which can be loaded in nunit manually but now i want to do it automatically from my application

Comment: It does have NUnit, included. NCover does not work without Unit testing framework, like NUnit. NCover is a code coverage tool, which calculates how much of your code is covered by the tests you have written.

Comment: check this http://testdriven.net/overview.aspx, you can even debug it. I have been using it for quite sometime.

Comment: ya that's true but i need to integrate the execution part of nunit in my project can u get me

Comment: @nils - from how I read it, he is trying to integrate NUnit into his app, not into VS

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to run NUnit from your exe?

Unless you go to a lot of trouble, it sounds to me like the best option would be to include the NUnit console exe (and dlls) in your package, and execute via `Process.Start`, capturing stdout (or writing to a file, which may be simpler). Then parse the output file.

It might not be as pretty as the GUI version, but it will probably be easier to deploy.

Comment: can u please explain in detail ?

Comment: I don't have detailed notes, since I haven't done it... but if (for whatever reason) you want to exec NUnit at runtime (presumably to test downstream code), you would have to ship the necessary NUnit assemblies etc with your app. It sounds like it *should* work... but again: I haven't tried it...